# Parse Data and Javascript/HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the Data module from [Parse](http://parse.com). I'm using HTML to create an email form. I use Javascript to get the form data (email), and then generate a username from the email address. This information is then saved to the Parse database.

Here's the HTML form code:

```
<form method="post" class="center">
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type your email to create a Mail Link" />
    <button id="submit" onclick="formSubmit();">Create</button>
</form>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
function formSubmit() {
    var emailValue = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var userValue = emailValue.substr(0, emailValue.indexOf('@'));

    Parse.initialize("---KEY---", "---KEY---");
    var Users = Parse.Object.extend("Users");
    var users = new Users();
    users.save({username: userValue}).then(function(object) {
        alert("Saved user");
    });
    users.save({email: emailValue}).then(function(object) {
        alert("Saved email");
    });
}
```

The problem is that the console is showing that the values are saved, however the data isn't saved into Parse.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I awarded Indra the bounty, but here's the full answer for more context. This is an annoying problem, but you can solve it.

First, the form should use onsubmit.

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="formSubmit();">
```

Second, your function should use Indra's method to save data. **But, you need `event.preventDefault();` before it.**

```
event.preventDefault();
    userList.save({
       username: "Peter Adams"
       }, {
          success: function(userList) {
             alert('Success');
          },
          error: function(userList, error) {
             alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
          }
    });
```

Comment: I don't think you need to use the onSubmit method of the form, event onclick event of button was enough for it, and if you use onclick event no need of the event.preventDefault(). just change users.save method, your other code is fine.

Answer (score 1):

In can make button a simple button, no need to change the button to a button as mention in the link you've mentioned, your code'll work fine.

You've written .then() method after saving the user data, but actually it's called to run the callbacks when the promise is fulfilled.

But here you're using simple Parse.Object, so either you've to use Parse.Promise, or if you want to use only simple Parse.Object when something like:-

```
users.save({
username: "Jake Cutter"
}, {
success: function(userObject) {
  alert('The save was successful');
},
error: function(userObject, error) {
  // The save failed.  Error is an instance of Parse.Error.
  // Do something if you want to do on error
}
});
```

For details you can check:-
https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#save
https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Promise.html#then

Comment: Indra, you get the bounty. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to store the form values and create a **sub class** of your **parse class** and also a new **parse object** to store the values in parse.

Example:

```
<form id="contact-form" >
        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
        <br>
        Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
        email:<br>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
        <a href="/access2"><input type="submit" value="Get Access" /></a>
    </form>
```

Javascript code:

```
    Parse.initialize("--KEY--", "--KEY--");

var Subscribers = Parse.Object.extend('Subscribers'); //create local parse object from your Parse class

$('#contact-form').submit(function(e) {
//on form submit
    e.preventDefault();

    //get data from form
    var data = {
        firstname: $("#firstname").val(),
        lastname: $("#lastname").val(),
        email: $("#email").val()
    };

    //create new Parse object
    subscribers = new Subscribers();

    //match the key values from the form, to your parse class, then save it
    subscribers.save(data, {
    //if successful
        success: function(parseObj) {
                alert(subscribers.get('firstname') + " " + subscribers.get('lastname') + " " + subscribers.get('email') + " saved to Parse.")
            }
        ,
        error: function(parseObj, error) {
            console.log(parseObj);
            console.log(error);
        }   
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all for me. Replaced the appid and javascript key runed the code but nothing happened on my parse app

Comment: Do you have jquery installed? if you inspect element does it throw an error on the dollar sign? and also parse should be imported in your project. also make sure you replace --KEY-- with your parse app api key